# Determining whether composition of two functions is bijective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Question:

Let $ \ A $ be the set of odd integers and $ \ B $ the set of even integers.

Let $ \ f: A \times B \to A \times A$, via $ \ f(a,b) = (3a -b, a+b)$.

Let $ \ g : A\times A \to B \times A$ via $ \ g(c,d) = (c-d, 2c -d)$

(a) Compute $ \ (g\circ f) (3,8)$

(b) Is $ \ g\circ f$ injective? Is it surjective?

My attempt:

$ \ g\circ f: A \times B \to B \times A$ via $ \ (g\circ f) (x,y) = (2(x-y), 5x -3y)$

$ \ (g\circ f)(3,8) = (-10,-9)$

Im not sure if this function is injective and surjective. I can't come up with any counter examples.

Comment: think you might want to plug in your numbers again, for what you show in your attempt.

Comment: Sorry I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $h: A \times B \rightarrow B \times A$ by $h(x,y) = (2x-2y, 5x-3y)$.

**Claim:** $h$ is not surjective.

Proof:  The point $(0,1)$ is not in the image of $h$.  If it were, there would be a point $(x,y) \in A \times B$ with $h(x,y) = (2x-2y, 5x-3y) = (0,1)$.  This implies that $2x-2y=0$, so that $x=y$.  But $x$ is odd and $y$ is even, so this is a contradiction.

**Claim:** $h$ is injective.

Proof:  Suppose that $h(x,y)=h(a,b)$.  This says that $2x-2y=2a-2b$, so we get $x-y=a-b$, or $x=y+a-b$.   The second coordinates give us $5x-3y=5a-3b$.  Substitute in $x=y+a-b$ and do the algebra, and you'll get $y=b$.  Plug this back in to $x=y+a-b$ to see that $x=a$.  We now have $(x,y)=(a,b)$, so $h$ is injective.

Comment: Is it injective?